# Trying to list all the mondays and their dates in a year

Tags: vb.net, date

I'm trying to list all the mondays and their dates in, let's say, 2014. I don't know what's wrong with my code below (probably the loop). When I execute these, the program crashes.

```
    Dim d1 As DateTime = #1/1/2014#
    Dim d2 As DateTime = d1.AddDays(-(d1.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday))

    Do
        ListBox1.Items.Add(d2.ToString("MMM - dd - yyyy   ddd"))
        d2.AddDays(7)
    Loop While (d2.Year < 2015)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `DateTime` instance is *immutable*, meaning that it cannot be changed. The `d2.AddDays(7)` expression creates a *new* instance with a different value, which you can assign back to `d2`:

```
d2 = d2.AddDays(7)
```

So why does your program crash? Since the date never changes, it will never hit 2015, and your program will try to add infinitely many items to the listbox. Obviously you will run out of memory before that happens, which makes the program crash.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reassign the value from the AddDays to the variable used to test the exist condition

```
 d2 = d2.AddDays(7)
```

Without this, the loop never ends because the exit condition is never met.

Looking at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of days to the
>   value of this instance

By the way, your code lists also a date for 2013, I suggest to start with the initial value set to

```
Dim d1 As DateTime = #1/7/2014#
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that might work for you:

```
Private Function GetAllWeekdays(inYear As Integer, dayOfWeek As System.DayOfWeek) As List(Of Date)
    Dim currDate As New Date(inYear, 1, 1) 'start jan 1st
    GetAllWeekdays = New List(Of Date)

    For i = 1 To (New Date(inYear, 12, 31) - New Date(inYear, 1, 1)).Days
        currDate = currDate.AddDays(1)
        If (currDate.DayOfWeek = dayOfWeek) Then GetAllWeekdays.Add(currDate)
    Next
End Function
```

It loops through all the days in the provided year and returns just the days with the `System.DayOfWeek` that you provide.

You can use it like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.ListBox1.DataSource = GetAllWeekdays(2014, DayOfWeek.Monday)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a iterator block?

```
Private Iterator Function DateSequence( _
        start As DateTime, _
        step As TimeSpan) As IEnumerable(Of DateTime)

    While True
        start = start.Add(step)
        Yield start
    End While
End Function
```

Which allows you to do some linq,

```
Dim firstDay = 'excercise for reader
Dim step = TimeSpan.FromDays(7)
var days = DateSequence(firstDay, step).Take(53) _
        .Where(Function(d) d.Year = firstDay.Year)
```